# UICollectionView not adding cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UITableViewCell` that contains a `UICollectionView`. Each collection view can have a max of 3 cells. I am adding the cells with this code.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    collectionIndex++;
    return [[collectionCellData objectAtIndex:collectionIndex] count];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"collection Cell: %@", indexPath);
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"availableTimeCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"Data: %@", [collectionCellData objectAtIndex:collectionIndex]);

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
    [label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir Next" size:13.0]];
    [label setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.108 green:0.550 blue:1.000 alpha:1.000]];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString *startTimeString = [[[collectionCellData objectAtIndex:collectionIndex] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"startTimestamp"];
    NSLog(@"Start Time String: %@", startTimeString);
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:startTimeString];
    NSLog(@"New Date: %@", date);
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"h:mm a"];

    NSString *newDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"NEW NEW Date: %@", newDate);
    label.text = newDate;
    [cell addSubview:label];
    return cell;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(53, 17);
}
```

My `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableCeption:(BJTableCeption *)tableCeption cellForItem:(id)item
{
    NSArray *topLevelObjects;
    EngagementListCell *cell;
    if ([item isKindOfClass:[BJItemObject class]]) {

        cell = (EngagementListCell *)[tableCeption dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"EngagementListCell"];

        if (cell == nil) {
            topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"EngagementListCells" owner:nil options:nil];
            cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        cell.lblStaff.text = [((AppointmentGrid *)((BJItemObject *)item).item).employeeObject valueForKey:@"displayName"]; // Staff name
        cell.availableTimeCollection.dataSource = self;
        cell.availableTimeCollection.delegate = self;
        [cell.availableTimeCollection registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"availableTimeCell"];

        [collectionCellData addObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[((AppointmentGrid *)((BJItemObject *)item).item) slots]]];
        NSLog(@"cell data: %@", collectionCellData);
        [cell.availableTimeCollection reloadData];


    } else {
        cell = (EngagementListCell *)[tableCeption dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ServiceHeaderCell"];

        if (cell == nil) {
            topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"EngagementListCells" owner:nil options:nil];
            cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:1];
        }
        cell.lblService.text = ((BJCategoryObject *)item).item; // Service name
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Log output

```
2014-01-28 08:39:42.818 Customer View[30896:70b] Start Time String: 2014-01-30 08:00:00
2014-01-28 08:39:42.819 Customer View[30896:70b] New Date: 2014-01-30 15:00:00 +0000
2014-01-28 08:39:42.819 Customer View[30896:70b] NEW NEW Date: 8:00 AM
2014-01-28 08:39:42.819 Customer View[30896:70b] collection Cell: <NSIndexPath: 0x9099470> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}
2014-01-28 08:39:42.820 Customer View[30896:70b] Data: (
        {
        endTimestamp = "2014-01-30 08:05:00";
        slotDuration = 5;
        startTimestamp = "2014-01-30 08:00:00";
    }
)
2014-01-28 08:39:42.820 Customer View[30896:70b] Start Time String: 2014-01-30 08:00:00
2014-01-28 08:39:42.821 Customer View[30896:70b] New Date: 2014-01-30 15:00:00 +0000
2014-01-28 08:39:42.821 Customer View[30896:70b] NEW NEW Date: 8:00 AM
2014-01-28 08:39:42.821 Customer View[30896:70b] collection Cell: <NSIndexPath: 0x90a3130> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}
2014-01-28 08:39:42.822 Customer View[30896:70b] Data: (
        {
        endTimestamp = "2014-01-30 08:05:00";
        slotDuration = 5;
        startTimestamp = "2014-01-30 08:00:00";
    },
        {
        endTimestamp = "2014-01-30 08:10:00";
        slotDuration = 5;
        startTimestamp = "2014-01-30 08:05:00";
    },
        {
        endTimestamp = "2014-01-30 08:15:00";
        slotDuration = 5;
        startTimestamp = "2014-01-30 08:10:00";
    }
)
2014-01-28 08:39:42.822 Customer View[30896:70b] Start Time String: 2014-01-30 08:00:00
2014-01-28 08:39:42.822 Customer View[30896:70b] New Date: 2014-01-30 15:00:00 +0000
2014-01-28 08:39:42.823 Customer View[30896:70b] NEW NEW Date: 8:00 AM
2014-01-28 08:39:42.823 Customer View[30896:70b] collection Cell: <NSIndexPath: 0x90d7eb0> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}
2014-01-28 08:39:42.823 Customer View[30896:70b] Data: (
        {
        endTimestamp = "2014-01-30 08:05:00";
        slotDuration = 5;
        startTimestamp = "2014-01-30 08:00:00";
    },
        {
        endTimestamp = "2014-01-30 08:10:00";
        slotDuration = 5;
        startTimestamp = "2014-01-30 08:05:00";
    },
        {
        endTimestamp = "2014-01-30 08:15:00";
        slotDuration = 5;
        startTimestamp = "2014-01-30 08:10:00";
    }
)
2014-01-28 08:39:42.823 Customer View[30896:70b] Start Time String: 2014-01-30 08:05:00
2014-01-28 08:39:42.824 Customer View[30896:70b] New Date: 2014-01-30 15:05:00 +0000
2014-01-28 08:39:42.824 Customer View[30896:70b] NEW NEW Date: 8:05 AM
2014-01-28 08:39:42.824 Customer View[30896:70b] collection Cell: <NSIndexPath: 0x9091980> {length = 2, path = 0 - 2}
2014-01-28 08:39:42.825 Customer View[30896:70b] Data: (
        {
        endTimestamp = "2014-01-30 08:05:00";
        slotDuration = 5;
        startTimestamp = "2014-01-30 08:00:00";
    },
        {
        endTimestamp = "2014-01-30 08:10:00";
        slotDuration = 5;
        startTimestamp = "2014-01-30 08:05:00";
    },
        {
        endTimestamp = "2014-01-30 08:15:00";
        slotDuration = 5;
        startTimestamp = "2014-01-30 08:10:00";
    }
)
2014-01-28 08:39:42.825 Customer View[30896:70b] Start Time String: 2014-01-30 08:10:00
2014-01-28 08:39:42.826 Customer View[30896:70b] New Date: 2014-01-30 15:10:00 +0000
2014-01-28 08:39:42.826 Customer View[30896:70b] NEW NEW Date: 8:10 AM
2014-01-28 08:39:42.826 Customer View[30896:70b] collection Cell: <NSIndexPath: 0x906ddc0> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}
2014-01-28 08:39:42.827 Customer View[30896:70b] Data: (
        {
        endTimestamp = "2014-01-30 08:05:00";
        slotDuration = 5;
        startTimestamp = "2014-01-30 08:00:00";
    },
        {
        endTimestamp = "2014-01-30 08:10:00";
        slotDuration = 5;
        startTimestamp = "2014-01-30 08:05:00";
    },
        {
        endTimestamp = "2014-01-30 08:15:00";
        slotDuration = 5;
        startTimestamp = "2014-01-30 08:10:00";
    }
)
2014-01-28 08:39:42.827 Customer View[30896:70b] Start Time String: 2014-01-30 08:00:00
2014-01-28 08:39:42.827 Customer View[30896:70b] New Date: 2014-01-30 15:00:00 +0000
2014-01-28 08:39:42.828 Customer View[30896:70b] NEW NEW Date: 8:00 AM
2014-01-28 08:39:42.828 Customer View[30896:70b] collection Cell: <NSIndexPath: 0x906dde0> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}
2014-01-28 08:39:42.828 Customer View[30896:70b] Data: (
        {
        endTimestamp = "2014-01-30 08:05:00";
        slotDuration = 5;
        startTimestamp = "2014-01-30 08:00:00";
    },
        {
        endTimestamp = "2014-01-30 08:10:00";
        slotDuration = 5;
        startTimestamp = "2014-01-30 08:05:00";
    },
        {
        endTimestamp = "2014-01-30 08:15:00";
        slotDuration = 5;
        startTimestamp = "2014-01-30 08:10:00";
    }
)
2014-01-28 08:39:42.828 Customer View[30896:70b] Start Time String: 2014-01-30 08:05:00
2014-01-28 08:39:42.829 Customer View[30896:70b] New Date: 2014-01-30 15:05:00 +0000
2014-01-28 08:39:42.829 Customer View[30896:70b] NEW NEW Date: 8:05 AM
2014-01-28 08:39:42.829 Customer View[30896:70b] collection Cell: <NSIndexPath: 0x906de70> {length = 2, path = 0 - 2}
2014-01-28 08:39:42.830 Customer View[30896:70b] Data: (
        {
        endTimestamp = "2014-01-30 08:05:00";
        slotDuration = 5;
        startTimestamp = "2014-01-30 08:00:00";
    },
        {
        endTimestamp = "2014-01-30 08:10:00";
        slotDuration = 5;
        startTimestamp = "2014-01-30 08:05:00";
    },
        {
        endTimestamp = "2014-01-30 08:15:00";
        slotDuration = 5;
        startTimestamp = "2014-01-30 08:10:00";
    }
)
2014-01-28 08:39:42.830 Customer View[30896:70b] Start Time String: 2014-01-30 08:10:00
2014-01-28 08:39:42.831 Customer View[30896:70b] New Date: 2014-01-30 15:10:00 +0000
2014-01-28 08:39:42.831 Customer View[30896:70b] NEW NEW Date: 8:10 AM
2014-01-28 08:39:42.831 Customer View[30896:70b] collection Cell: <NSIndexPath: 0x90677c0> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}
2014-01-28 08:39:42.832 Customer View[30896:70b] Data: (
        {
        endTimestamp = "2014-01-30 08:05:00";
        slotDuration = 5;
        startTimestamp = "2014-01-30 08:00:00";
    }
)
2014-01-28 08:39:42.832 Customer View[30896:70b] Start Time String: 2014-01-30 08:00:00
2014-01-28 08:39:42.832 Customer View[30896:70b] New Date: 2014-01-30 15:00:00 +0000
2014-01-28 08:39:42.833 Customer View[30896:70b] NEW NEW Date: 8:00 AM
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Should look like

[image]

My issue is even though the `numberOfItemsInSection` is returning 3 sometimes, it will only display the first cell with the time of 8:00 AM for all.

Am I doing this correctly or am I doing something wrong when it comes to populating the cells for the collection view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a few potential problems:

First, it looks like `collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:` expects to always be called sequentially from section 0...N, which is not the case, so your iterator variable `collectionIndex` will probably not work as expected.

Second, looks like you're populating the data model for the collection views (`collectionCellData`) in the table view delegate method. If `BJTableCeption` works like `UITableView`, this may also cause problems, as `cellForItem:` would be called many times, resulting in extra objects in `collectionCellData`.

Third, after dequeuing your collection cells, the labels are added to the cell each time. Thus, if a collection cell is reused, it will have duplicate labels piled on top of each other. You should create a custom subclass that creates its subviews only when initialized.

I recommend populating the `collectionCellData` array once, before the collection cells are reloaded (`viewDidLoad` or `initWithNibName:bundle:` are good places to put your setup code). In `cellForItem:`, assign the `tag` property of each collection view with the row that contains it; then, use the tag instead of `collectionIndex` in `collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:`.

Comment: Yes, it's fine to register classes with the collection view there; even if you re-register a class/nib for a reuse identifier, it will just replace the old entry.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the help. I used your approach but instead of using the tag, I created a subclass and stored the data array in a variable, then just accessed the data from that collectionView. I also switched the registerClass to a registerNib and made my cell in a xib so that I don't have to create and add a label.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, your `-collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:` method looks highly suspect. That method should simply return the number of items that currently exist in the specified section. You're incrementing `collectionIndex`, which is probably an instance variable, and using the result to look something up in an array. That means that the result doesn't depend on the specified section, but on the number of times that the method has been called previously.

Whatever else might be going on in your code, I don't see how what you're doing in that method can possibly be correct.

Another problem: the code in `-collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` always creates a new label and adds it to the cell. The collection view will recycle cells when they're no longer needed, so a cell may be reused many times. Your code will add a new label each time the cell is reused, which means that you could end up with dozens or hundreds of similar labels.

Comment: That is what I am doing. After testing, the numberOfItemsInSection is called directly before the cellForItem call. Since I have a multi dimensional array of the items, I use the instance variable to increment which section to lookup.

Comment: I figured it was something because of the reuse of the cell. Do you have any suggestions on how to get this to work?